# "No value accessor for form control with path" despite using formBuilder.control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to procedurally generate an Angular form based on some settings information found in our backend. To do this a request is sent to retrieve the data and then I'm trying to build a reactive form based on that data.

`dynamicValue` is the current value of a setting, in the case of a toggle switch it'll be either true or false.

The below code creates a FormGroup, which contains a formArray which then has the value of each setting in the settingsData array pushed to a new control.

Component:

```
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      settingsArray: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

    this.settingsData.forEach((settings: ClientSetting) => {
      this.settingsArray.push(
        this.formBuilder.control(settings.dynamicValue)
      )
    });
```

And then in my template I'm doing this

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
        <div formArrayName="settingsArray">
          <div *ngFor="let settings of settingsArray.controls; let i = index">
                <app-boolean-setting [formControlName]="i" [settingData]="settingsData[i]"></app-boolean-setting>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

App-boolean-setting template

```
<div class="cont">
    <span>{{settingData.description.label}}</span>
    <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="{{formControlName}}" checked="{{settingData.description}}"></mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

The app-boolean-setting component just has two inputs:

```
@Input() public settingData: ClientSetting;
@Input() public formControlName: string;
```

However when I run the code I'm getting two errors:

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with path: 'settingsArray -> 0'
```

and this one, which is an error within the BooleanSetting template as it seems to not be able to find the formGroup even though it's within the div in the parent component which has `[formGroup]="form"` declared?

```
Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
```

Answer (score 2):

[formControlName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#selectors) name is already used by angular to create instance of formControlDirective. So change your Input property to some other name something like this.

**app-boolean-setting.ts**

```
@Input() public settingData: ClientSetting;
@Input() public customFormControlName: string;
```

**component.ts**

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
        <div formArrayName="settingsArray">
          <div *ngFor="let settings of settingsArray.controls; let i = index">
                <app-boolean-setting [customFormControlName]="i" [settingData]="settingsData[i]"></app-boolean-setting>
         </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer did not exist, I would have spent a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Jake, Futhermore Chellppan say, you can not use in App-boolean-setting `formControlName="{{formControlName}}"` alone

One way easy to solve is that your app-boolean-settings has as input a FormControl

```
  //in your app-boolean-settings
  control:FormControl
  @Input('control') set f(value:AbstractControl)
  {
    this.control=value as FormControl
  }

  <div class="cont">
     <span>{{settingData.description.label}}</span>
     <!--use directly [formControl]="control"-->
     <!-don't use checked to give value, the slide get the value of the control (*)->
     <mat-slide-toggle [formControl]="control">
      </mat-slide-toggle>
  </div>
```

And you use

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="settingsArray">
      <div *ngFor="let settings of settingsArray.controls; let i = index">
            <!--see how you pass directly the "FormControl"-->
            <app-boolean-setting [control]="settings"
              [settingData]="settingsData[i]"></app-boolean-setting>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(*)About remove `checked="{{settingData.description}}"`, when you has a input, mat-input, mat-slide-toggle,... that has already a formControl, this get the value of the formControl